# document.getElementById().style.display = 'block' reading error or skips custom CSS

Tags: javascript, css, vimeo-api

I have a Vidalytics video that I embed on a landing page and I want to show a button 15 minutes into the video.

From a course I got this script:

```
<script>
  var TIME_TO_SHOW_THINGS = 10; // in seconds
  var HIDDEN_CONTENT_ID = 'section-f38aa7fe'
  var EMBED_CODE_ID = 'vidalytics_embed_VnMuXxlnXGcJft2R'; // replace with own embedcode ID
  var EMBED_CODE_RETURNING_KEY = EMBED_CODE_ID + '_returning'
  if (!localStorage.getItem(EMBED_CODE_RETURNING_KEY)) {
    function checkVideoTime() {
      var embeds = (_vidalytics || {}).embeds || {};
      if (embeds[EMBED_CODE_ID]) {
        var player = embeds[EMBED_CODE_ID].player || {};
        if (player.getCurrentVideoTime) {
          var currentTime = player.getCurrentVideoTime();
          if (currentTime >= TIME_TO_SHOW_THINGS) {
            showHiddenItem();
            return;
          }
          
        }
      }  
      setTimeout(checkVideoTime, 1000);
    }
    checkVideoTime();
    localStorage.setItem(EMBED_CODE_RETURNING_KEY, true);
  } else {
    showHiddenItem();
  }
  function showHiddenItem() {
      document.getElementById(HIDDEN_CONTENT_ID).style.display = 'block';
  }
</script>
```

I cannot add custom CSS in the system I use, so I used a custom HTML block where I first added

```
<style>
#section-f38aa7fe {
display: none;
}
</style>
```

And then added the script right after it.

I also embedded the video with a separate custom HTML block.

I can add script in the header and footer.

Tried both.

When I use the script in Custom HTML or in the Header I get an error, because the element isn't loaded yet.

But when I add it in the footer, the system states that all DOM elements wil be available for scripts. And indeed, I do see the element appear when the script is in the footer. But it doesn't adhere to the set delay time. It immediately loads the element.

Or, when I add !important to the style element, then it doesn't load at all. No errors, but also not shown on delay.

2 questions:

1. Most important part is to get this working. Can anybody help me out?
2. Ideally I would get this working with Vimeo. Is that as easy as changing the embed code ID?
   Or would I need a completely different script for it?

Comment: Does this script run before the DOM loads? If so, the element you're attempting to retrieve with `document.getElementById(HIDDEN_CONTENT_ID)` would not exist yet.

Comment: When I add the script to the footer the system explicitly states that all DOM elements will be available.

Because of your question, I moved the code to the footer, but now it ignores the display:none that is part of the custom HTML block

Comment: You say 15 _minutes_ into the video, but all I can see in the code that appears to be related, is `var TIME_TO_SHOW_THINGS = 10; // in seconds` ...?

Comment: _"Ideally I would get this working with Vimeo. Is that as easy as changing the embed code ID?"_ - no, most likely not, because the APIs used to communicate with the player to get the current play time, will likely differ. And the `var embeds = (_vidalytics || {}).embeds || {};` will probably need replacing with something else as well.

Comment: @CBroe, yes, that's because I'm testing and I don't want to wait 15 mins :D. I disabled the videocontrols, so I'm testing with watching 10 seconds. If I get it working, I will increase the seconds.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for your explanation on Vimeo. I guess it will take me days to figure it out by myself haha. So I will stick to Vidalytics for now then.